# Getting "not authenticated" Error in Nuxt.js middleware with SSR and Amplify

Tags: nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, aws-amplify

I would like to create a Nuxt.js middleware to check if an user is authenticated or not. That works fine while navigation inside of the app. But when I refresh the page I always get:

```
[ERROR] 43:48.846 foo - SERVER {                                                                  15:43:48  
  error: 'not authenticated'
}
 ERROR  [ERROR] 43:48.844 AuthError -                                                                     15:43:48  
        Error: Amplify has not been configured correctly.
        The configuration object is missing required auth properties.
        Did you run `amplify push` after adding auth via `amplify add auth`?
        See https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#amplify-project-setup for more information
```

1. AWS Amplify has an article with SSR Support here: [SSR Support for AWS Amplify](https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/mobile/ssr-support-for-aws-amplify-javascript-libraries/)
   There you can find the code to enable SSR and checking for user authentication
2. In the Nuxt.js Docs, you can find:

> In universal mode, middlewares will be called once on server-side (on the first request to the Nuxt app, e.g. when directly accessing the app or refreshing the page) and on the client-side when navigating to further routes.

Alright, so I enabled SSR in my amplify plugin and adjusted the middleware:

```
if (process.server) {
const { Auth } = withSSRContext(context.req)
try {
  await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
} catch (error) {
  return context.redirect(302, '/auth/signin')
}
```

}

When I refresh the page, the code gets executed, but I always get a "not authenticated" error and "Amplify has not been configured correctly". On the other hand everything works perfectly fine on client side (signin, signup, etc.)

Any idea guys? I can't find a solution...

Kind regards

Comment: did you find solution to achieve this?

Comment: Im looking for it too. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to the same problem and it turned out I had to adjust my configuration. I'm in NextJS but it looks like the same issue. In changed the way I configured Amplify in my component from:

```
Amplify.configure({ ...config })
```

to

```
Amplify.configure({ ...config, ssr: true })
```

Without setting the `ssr` property, my server side code was not able to pickup the current authenticated user and all I got was 'The user is not authenticated' in the server logs.

I'm using aws-amplify@3.3.4

Answer (score 0):

Just try to configure Auth. No need to provide `ssr: true`.
At least thats what worked for me..

```
if (process.server) {
const { Auth } = withSSRContext(context.req)
Auth.configure({...config})
try {
  await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
} catch (error) {
  return context.redirect(302, '/auth/signin')
}
```